# Can't fetch data FROM API and insert into FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

Trying to fethch data and insert to Flatlist , can someone show my mistake, tried almost everything, Tried to make like in `Official Docs`, but didn't help:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://app.sm117.ru/api/v1/contract/news/'),{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}}

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json. ???  ))//what can i put here , cause i my Json doesnt have title
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      }, []);
  
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.id}, {item.title}</Text>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass nothing because your response already contains all the list.

```
.then((json) => setData(json))
```

If u will print the data or response you will get to know the better. Put console , things will be more clearer.

Let us consider this example.If you will consider this request.

```
https://reactnative.dev/movies.json
```

Here you have to put the `json.movies` to get all the list.

Answer (score 1):

You have a closing parenthesis after the url in the fetch call, it should look like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://app.sm117.ru/api/v1/contract/news/',{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}})
```

Comment: anyway can't fetch data , do u have your own method how to fetch it? ideas mayb

Comment: Try logging the data to the console to ensure it looks like how you think.
Also look into using "axios", it really helps simplify fetching data & takes care of converting to json (and a whole bunch of other really useful features).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you just have type mistake on this line:

```
  fetch('https://app.sm117.ru/api/v1/contract/news/'),{
                                                     ^
```

You should use `fetch()` like this:

```
let promise = fetch(url, [options])
```

Comment: anyway can't fetch data , do u have your own method how to fetch it? ideas mayb

Comment: You can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) : 
`import axios from 'axios'`
 `let data = axios.get('url_api_endpoint').then((response)=> response);`